# Spring RestTemplate getForObject() giving 401 unauthorized exception

Tags: java, spring, rest, prestashop, resttemplate

In my browser follwing rest API url is working and I can see XML results.

```
"http://V7846EKZZJ1OJAW486D66IS7GO24XKUZ@localhost:8090/prestashop/api/products/1"
```

I want to call this url from Java client and get results. For that I am using RestTemplate.

```
String result = restTemplate.getForObject("http://V7846EKZZJ1OJAW486D66IS7GO24XKUZ@localhost:8090/prestashop/api/products/1"
    , String.class);
```

this is giving following error,

```
WARNING: GET request for       http://V7846EKZZJ1OJAW486D66IS7GO24XKUZ@localhost:8090/prestashop/api/products/1 resulted in 401 (Unauthorized); invoking error handler
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49533', transport: 'socket'

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:537)
```

Not sure why this is happening. 
Can't we call URL in form username@host/appplication with RestTemplate?
Or is it incorrect the way I am calling this URL with RestTemplate?

regards,
-Lasith.

Comment: What happens when you use that URL from a browser? It looks like it needs a password too, or some other form of authentication?

Comment: No it doesn't need password. With browser it gives the product information which is in XML format.

Comment: Hi, I resolved this issue. It seems username@host/application is not recognize with Spring test template. So we need to set authorization manually. 
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    BasicCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =  new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password));
    httpClient.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar problem and solved it using **resttemplate.exchange** method. The steps are put your authentication details in RestRequestHeaderInfo which should be inside `HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>` pass this entity into the exchange method like below:

```
response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, Response.class);
```

If response is in json format like in my case, Response is the holder class for the corresponding data which will be populated by Jackson library in my classpath: It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use restTemplete interceptor to add token headers. This is better than exchange method since you dont have to add token everytime. Lambda expression for that is below

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder().interceptors((HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) -> {
  request.getHeaders().set(AUTHORIZATION, token);
  return execution.execute(request, body);}).build()
```